# pdfkit table items showing on separate pages after first page

Tags: node.js, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I'm trying to create a long table with pdfkit.

But once the table gets too long for the first page of the pdf, it starts separating each table item by page.

[image]

There are 92 pages below this last page that says '23'. The pages below say one item of the table; '23', '$40', 'flowers' etc... Each is in the correct x position but on its own separate page.

How to I get the table to work correctly after the first page?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const PDFGenerator = require('pdfkit');

const dummyOrders = [
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
  { price: '$40', name: 'flowers', paidOn: '1/2/22' },
];
const generateTable = (doc, orders) => {
  const tableTop = 150;
  const descriptionX = 270;
  const dateX = 400;
  const amountX = 139;
  const numX = 50;

  doc
    .fontSize(10)
    .text('Num', numX, tableTop, { bold: true })
    .text('Amount', amountX, tableTop, { bold: true })
    .text('Description', descriptionX, tableTop)
    .text('Date', dateX, tableTop);

  let i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
    const order = orders[i];
    const y = tableTop + 25 + i * 25;

    doc
      .fontSize(10)
      .text(i + 1, numX, y)
      .text(order.price, amountX, y)
      .text(order.name, descriptionX, y)
      .text(order.paidOn, dateX, y);
  }
};

const theOutput = new PDFGenerator();

const fileName = `Tax-info.pdf`;

// pipe to a writable stream which would save the result into the same directory
theOutput.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName));

generateTable(theOutput, dummyOrders);

// write out file
theOutput.end();
```